# Latex equation tags

Tags: equations, align, tags

I have an align environment of equations in two columns. I want to give custom tags to each line, but for the first two lines I want a common tag in the middle of the lines. Any ideas would be greatly appreciate it.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{align}
& \mbox{Replenishment Indicator:} & O_t  = & \{
      1,  \text{if } t=\sum_{\kappa=1}^k DIT_{\kappa} + PLT_k \tag{Output-O} \\
& & & \text{ for some $k$}; \hspace{0.3cm} \text{else, }0.  \} \\
& \mbox{Inventory Evolution:} & I_{t+1}^{ijmlp} =& (I_t^{ijmlp}-1)^+ + O_tf \tag{Output-I} \\
& \mbox{Per-day Unmet Demand:} & S_t^{ijmlp}  =& (1-I_t^{ijmlp})^+ \tag{Output-$S_t$}\\
& \mbox{Unmet Demand Fraction:} &  S^{ijmlp}  =& \sum_{t=0}^{3 \times 365} S_t^{ijmlp}  / 3 \times 365 \tag{Output-S} \\
& \mbox{Time to Fulfil Demand:}  & T^{ijmlp}  = & 3 \times 365 + \sum_{t=0}^{T^{ijmlp}} S_t^{ijmlp} \tag{Output-T} 
\end{align}
```

except I want `\tag{Output-O}` to be for the two lines, not just the first, while still keeping the alignment for the entire thing. Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, you need `&=`, not `=&` in terms of the alignment markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best way to present the data. However, a dirty trick seems to give what you're looking for.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\rb}[1]{\raisebox{3.5ex}{$\displaystyle#1$}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
& \rb{\text{Replenishment Indicator:}} & \rb{O_t}  &
  \rb{{}=\{1,\text{if }t=\sum_{\kappa=1}^k DIT_{\kappa}+PLT_k} \tag{Output-O} \\
& &  & \qquad\text{for some $k$}; \quad \text{else, }0.  \} \notag \\
& \text{Inventory Evolution:} & I_{t+1}^{ijmlp} &= (I_t^{ijmlp}-1)^+ + O_tf \tag{Output-I} \\
& \text{Per-day Unmet Demand:} & S_t^{ijmlp}  &= (1-I_t^{ijmlp})^+ \tag{Output-$S_t$}\\
& \text{Unmet Demand Fraction:} &  S^{ijmlp}  &= \sum_{t=0}^{3 \times 365} S_t^{ijmlp}  / 3 \times 365 \tag{Output-S} \\
& \text{Time to Fulfil Demand:}  & T^{ijmlp}  &= 3 \times 365 + \sum_{t=0}^{T^{ijmlp}} S_t^{ijmlp} \tag{Output-T} 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would consider a different format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\shortintertext{Replenishment Indicator:}
  &O_t = \biggl\{1,\text{if }t=\sum_{\kappa=1}^k DIT_{\kappa}+PLT_k
    \text{ for some $k$}; \quad \text{else, }0.  \biggr\} \tag{Output-O} \\
\shortintertext{Inventory Evolution:}
  &I_{t+1}^{ijmlp} = (I_t^{ijmlp}-1)^+ + O_tf \tag{Output-I} \\
\shortintertext{Per-day Unmet Demand:}
  &S_t^{ijmlp} = (1-I_t^{ijmlp})^+ \tag{Output-$S_t$}\\
\shortintertext{Unmet Demand Fraction:}
  &S^{ijmlp} = \sum_{t=0}^{3 \times 365} S_t^{ijmlp}  / 3 \times 365 \tag{Output-S} \\
\shortintertext{Time to Fulfil Demand:}
  &T^{ijmlp} = 3 \times 365 + \sum_{t=0}^{T^{ijmlp}} S_t^{ijmlp} \tag{Output-T}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, the dirty trick works great. I also like the suggested different format, if only I manage to install mathtools. Extremely helpful, thanks.